# Windows computer occasionally fails to resume from hibernation

Tags: windows-10, hibernate

I have a Windows 10 computer that I always hibernate instead of turn off. Every once in a while, however, when starting it up it would emit several starting beeps in rapid succession, instead of the usual one and then it would startup as if it has been completely shut down, i.e. failing to load the hibernation file in memory.

From what I know this can be caused either by the OS or the BIOS but I have no idea how to troubleshoot or fix the issue.

There are no meaningful events in the event viewer. Only "The previous system shutdown was unexpected." but with the timestamp of the time I started the computer.

Comment: Update both BIOS and the Power Management Driver.  Restart will occur. Then test hibernation again.

Answer (score 1):

Several beeps on startup is most likely your BIOS is trying to tell you something is wrong.

The user manual or online documentation of your laptop/motherboard vendor might help you out as the amount and length of beeps should correspond with an error code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).